# MS Analysis Services - measure values being assign to the wrong attribute member

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I've created a SSAS project to build a simple OLAP Cube. I'm using SSAS 2008 and SQL Server 2008 as well as the source data.

The cube is based on a single view. 
From this view I get a single measure (integer data type) and a single dimension with 7 dimension attributes. I'm not hardcoding any MDX.

I'm then using excel with a pivot table to explore the data.

The problem is that, when I browse the cube, for some dimension attributes there are some measure values being assign randomly to the wrong attribute member. I say randomly because this assignment changes every time I reprocess the cube.

Any help on this would be great!
Many Thanks

Comment: In order to help you we need to have details about your data source view, the actual database objects in it, and the mapping between dsv and the cube / dimensions. To begin with, are your fact table and your dimension table based on a "table"/"view" of the database, or are they defined via named queries?

Comment: Can you run this BIDS Helper feature on all your dimensions and report back any errors it gives you about multiple values? http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dimension%20Health%20Check&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I Giorgos, My data source view has one single obejct witch is a view and both fact and dimensions are based on this single view. I  have no named queries.

Comment: I Greg, I'll try to find how to run BIDS Helper Feature and I'll feedback you. If you can please give me some detail about how to do it. Thanks

Comment: I again, I run Dimension Health Check and it returns that "No Problems were found"

Comment: Hi all. For now I solve the problem by splitting the dimension. A create a new dim just for the attribute witch was genarating the problem. The dimension attribute key was created on the view used in the dsv with sql server ROW_NUMBER() function, and the problem I was having might be related to that. Thanks for all your help anyway.